# Gitflow in multi-products production

Tags: git

I've been working with git for some years and I used it to develop software products, as apps and embedded code.
Now I have to handle a multi-products production which can me described as follows:

- There is a main core containing some libraries which are shared between all different products
- Products are divided in families
- Families are divided in products

I have to organize the gitflow to manage code of all products.
As you can immagine, each family uses the core-libraries and implements some specialized code needed for all products of the family but, at the same time, each product needs to specialize part of this code to meet the clients requirements. 
I was able to focus on two possibile solutions, each of one with its pro and cons.

**Solution 1: repo-per-family**

I can create a git repo in which store all the core-libraries core and then create **one** repo for each family. In this way, I can import as sub-module the core-libraries, but, to differentiate all products, I should create a branch for each product. Such a solution is not so usable, since no code is shared between the products of the same family and each changes on a branch should be reported on the others one. Therefore, in this solution, I will create a number n of branches which will never merge.

**Solution 2: repo-per-product**

The same core-libraries repo should be created, but now I could create a repo for the "family-code" and finally create another repo for each specific product. This will allow me to handle both the core-code and the family-code, but will generate and explosive-number of repo which does not sound good (for me)

Really I don't know how manage this so-diversificate code. I try to analyze the code to understand if the parts that differentiate each product of the family could be encapsulated in some "settings file" but this is not possibile.
I hope I was clear enough..
Any help or suggestion is highly welcome!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's a little contradictory, products and families can't be subsets of each other unless they are the same exact thing.

[Gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) is a branching strategy, not really a product suite architecture guardrail.

The shared libraries can be placed into repos of their own.  This will allow greater reusability and relieve any dependency nightmares when products are using different versions.

Each product should be it's own project space, and then each family it's own repo.  If your "families" are very small, it might be worth considering combining a few of them if they fill very niche roles.

This an architectural question, so you might get a better answer on [the software engineering exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).